# Implementation of ECC in C

Tags: c, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I would like to implement «my own hybrid encryption engine» using the asymmetric elliptic curve cryptography instead of other algorithms as RSA or ElGamal.

Assuming that I want to use curves that provide greater security, which ones should I employ? Based on what I've read I think that probably the 521-bit curve is ideal. Are there more secure schemes?

What are the most secure implementations in C/C++ (without using the C++ STL) against, for example, side-channel attacks? I would like to implement it as a «separate» module, so I would appreciate clean source code or good references.

Comment: Your own "hybrid" engine? **Beware.** The First Rule of Cryptography is "you can't do a better job than the professionals." It is extremely likely that any changes you make to existing algorithms will weaken them, unless you have a background in cryptography and understand fully how encryption schemes work--and even then, you might weaken the encryption.

Comment: Are you going to protect your nation's nuclear weapon codes with that 521-bit elliptic curve crypto? Just wondering what secrets you might have that a standard implementation of FIPS 186-3 with a prime size of 256 bits or all simply curve-25519 isn't good enough for. Those are readily available, orders of magnitude faster, and it's not like there's a reasonable chance that either of these will be broken during your lifetime, nor that factoring the EC will be the point of entry in the first place (when it's so much more likely to find an implementation exploit or do social engineering).

Comment: That "first rule" fails at zero.

Comment: Jonathan, I have not modified the encryption schemes, It is probably more like building my «own» cryptographically safe communication protocol instead of implementing the full SSL support, and I haven't even implemented the algorithms. Basically, I am looking for secure implementations of the ECC in C/C++ (without the C++ STL)...

Comment: Damon, I would like to know what schemes should be efficient and secure enough, personally, I do not care if, for example, Quantum Computers will break current PK algorithms as RSA or the EC crypto in the future... I have read that the 521-bit ECC is equivalent to 15360-bit RSA/DSA, which is enough security... as you said, implementation exploits are more likely. I have asked for secure implementations against exploits.

Answer (score 1):

Before even thinking about whether any of the standard curves might not be secure enough, I'd just go and make sure that the encryption mode really is secure against plain old chosen ciphertext attacks.
I think the paper by Cramer and Shoup  "Design and Analysis of Practical Public-Key Encryption Schemes Secure against Adaptive Chosen Ciphertext Attack", 2003 is a good starting point for analyzing hybrid encryption schemes.

As for timing attacks: OpenSSL contains implementations for a small number of selected number of curves that have been implemented so that they run in constant time.